# Issue with Highchart tooltips and line for series for Line Chart

Tags: highcharts

Please refer to following jsFiddle from HighCharts demos

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/offset/)

To reproduce issue faced by me, please replace code in JavaScript portion with 
following code

```
    $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        marginLeft: 120
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        offset: 10
    },

    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        },
        tickWidth: 1,
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: [0, 0, 0, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]

});
});
```

After replacing, if you click on Run Report, you will see that the points touching the x-axis are not connected by series line colored blue. Also tooltips don't appear when we mouseover on these points.

Can somebody please help me in resolving this issue ?

I want to achieve following two things

1. Show tooltip even for points directly touching x-axis from series in blue
2. Show connected blue line of series between points where series value is 0

Assigning min: 0 for Y-axis is must for me as I don't want to show -ve values on Y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is known bug reported to our developers https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1687 / https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/946